# Overlay particles.js on fullscreen div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following .js plugin:

https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

With bootstrap 3's jumbotron, I have got the plugin working and my jumbotron is fullscreen when you get to my homepage (I think this is the issue) I am trying to run particles.js UNDER my jumbotron but for some reason the particles generate a whole viewport underneath my jumbotron. Like it is set up in it's own DIV after my jumbotron unit but I have `<div id="particles-js"></div>` wrapped around my jumbotron DIV. Which is where I get lost, the way I have it set up it should display underneath my jumbotron content and everything.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="particles-js">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container center-vertically">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">
                <h1>
                    A template with a bit of a different <strong>look &amp; feel</strong>.
                </h1>
                <hr>
                <p>Particles is a fun and multipurpose template, with clean &amp; modern design <i>+</i>&nbsp; code.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for the jumbotron as well as the particles-js ID:

```
.jumbotron { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 79px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    display: table;
}

#particles-js {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background: #6819e8; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #6819e8 0%, #7437d0 35%, #615fde 68%, #6980f2 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #6819e8 0%,#7437d0 35%,#615fde 68%,#6980f2 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #6819e8 0%,#7437d0 35%,#615fde 68%,#6980f2 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6819e8', endColorstr='#6980f2',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */ 
}

.center-vertically {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I have also uploaded a live version so it is easier to view the problem:

http://aliensix.com/company/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is make your `#particles-js` child of `.jumbotron`.

`#particles-js` needs to be positioned absolutely relative to the `.jumbotron`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    // Other style rules ...
}
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, it is closer but there is still some issues I cannot determine what is causing them, here is an updated demo with your fix: http://aliensix.com/company2/

Comment: Your #particles-js div should exist on its own. Not as the parent of jumbotron content.  So, basically, .jumbotron has two children, #particles-js and .container.center-vertically.

Comment: Yes I have it in the same order, the company2 link shows the result, for some reason the particles are going underneath the content and they also extend further than the first viewport.

Comment: No, you don't have it in same order. Right now, you have .jumbotron > #particles-js > .container.center-vertically

Comment: Oh I was reading what you said completely wrong! I get it now, so it is under the content now! I updated the link again: http://aliensix.com/company2/ but now for some reason the container has shifted to the right causing the text to be uncentered, do you have any idea what could this?